# Which questions need a good answer from Word of God at SLCC xFan 2015?

Tags: discussion, blog

I'll be attending SLCC Fan Xperience with press credentials this year. What questions needs good answers which might be supplied by the following celebrity panels / appearances?

Here is the list of people who will be in [panels](http://saltlakecomiccon.com/panel_schedule/), and therefore may be available for questions. *I make no guarantees that I'll be able to attend the panels, or ask any questions.*

- Mark Pellegrino - Dexter, Lost, Supernatural, Revolution
- Karen Gillan - Doctor Who, Guardians of the Galaxy
- Laurie Holden - The Walking Dead
- Christopher Lloyd - Back to the Future, Star Trek, Who Framed Roger Rabbit
- Brandon Routh - Arrow, Superman Returns
- Felicia Day - Supernatural
- Glenn Morshower - Transformers, Star Trek, X-Men: First Class
- Alaina Huffman - Stargate, Supernatural
- Tom Felton - Harry Potter
- Richard Paul Evans - Author of Michael Vey
- Ralph Macchio - The Karate Kid? I guess that's scifi/fantasy
- Robotech Industry Panel - `Join Harmony Gold's Tommy Yune and Steve Yun as they showcase all the latest live action and animated Robotech productions`
- Ray Park - G.I. Joe, Star Wars, X-Men
- Billie Piper - Doctor Who
- Morena Baccarin - Gotham, Firefly, V.

Suggest a question and the person you think might be able to answer it. I'll do my best. I'll also be writing posts for the blog about the show and my experiences.

Or peruse the http://saltlakecomiccon.com/ site if you see an exhibitor, booth, or celebrity you are interested in me checking out for you.

Comment: This is a great idea!

Comment: @Wikis Credit goes to Keen.

Answer (score 3):

**Billie Piper** -- What was the exact nature of Rose's relationship with the 9th and 10th doctors? (i.e. was there a romantic relationship, consummated or not, between Rose and the Doctor?)

This question might be horribly overdone in Who fandom, but it's a topic I've never personally explored online or otherwise. Perhaps **BESW** can weigh in on how worn out this topic is.

**Tom Felton** -- In light of Draco Malfoy's early characterization as a one-dimensional bully, if you've read J.K. Rowling's updated information about Draco, what are your thoughts on Draco's development into an almost reclusive figure, who eschews his parents' Muggle-hating values, collects Dark Arts artefacts, and develops a fascination with Alchemy? As Draco's actor, does this surprise you?

**Ralph Macchio** -- What is a yoot?

I suppose a more relevant question to sci-fi would be: **Why do you not age?**

These are my three suggestions.

Comment: I must admit that I can't really see "eschews his parents' Muggle-hating values" as a logical conclusion from JKR's Pottermore updates. He's not as much of a muggle hater, but that's not quite "[Eschewing](https://www.google.com/search?q=eschew&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8)". I think this argument of ours should go onto Memes page :)

Comment: Your tom Felton question was mostly answered.

Answer (score 3):

### Tom Felton

- What was Draco's boggart form (e.g. What was his greatest fear?)
- How do you *really* feel about being [sorted into Gryffindor](http://www.usmagazine.com/entertainment/news/draco-malfoy-actor-tom-felton-joins-pottermore-sorted-into-gryffindor-2015221)?

Comment: I *think* -- and I might be wrong, so take this with a grain of salt -- that JKR may have said at some point that Draco's Boggart was Voldemort. I've often wondered what Snape's Boggart is ... but then I, unfortunately, conclude it's something boring, like Lily's dead body. (Not that Voldemort is that much more exciting)

Comment: @Slytherincess - It wasn't JKR, it was in one of the videogames IIRC.

Comment: Your second question was answered

Comment: Excellent. I know @Slytherincess will be pleased :-)

Comment: For the 1st one its a ferret

Answer (score 3):

### Tom Felton

- Do you agree with JKR's view expressed in interviews, that all the girls who are deeply attracted to **Draco** (as opposed to the actor) are way wrong and shouldn't be?
- How much input into the personality of your character did you have from JKR?

Comment: These were both answered.

Answer (score 2):

## Karen Gilan

How do Rory and Amy wave to themselves in "Hungry Earth"? Why didn't create a **fixed point** in time?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Morena Baccarin

More **Firefly** *wheeennnnnnnnn?!*

Comment: I can answer that, never.

Comment: @JackBNimble: You can never answer this or you can answer this with “never”?

Comment: @Wrzlprmft the latter.

Comment: not until they reboot it.

Answer (score 1):

### Christopher Lloyd

- We've got two conflicting "[word of god](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/50482/what-is-the-basis-for-doc-brown-and-marty-mcflys-friendship)" answers to the question of why Marty and Doc were friends in the first place. Perhaps Mr Lloyd could give us his take on it?

Comment: Looking at the answers, I don't see any conflict; one is how they met, the other is why they were still hanging out. But it would be interesting to hear his take on it.

Answer (score 0):

### Ray Park

- Where did Maul Park his spaceship on Naboo?
- Was Maul the titular "Phantom Menace"?

Answer (score 0):

### Alaina Huffman

- What do *you* think happened in Stargate : Universe Season 3?

Comment: Since I have no idea the context of this question I'll have no idea if she answers it or not.

Comment: The Series finale episode (at the end of season 2) was a cliffhanger. The crew was in stasis and there was a real possibility that they might not survive the intergalactic journey ahead of them. Also, one of the crew members (Eli Wallace) was left outside of the cryotubes becase there wasn't enough spaces. Any hint she can give what she'd been told about the likely events of season 3 (especially her own story arc) would be of huge interest to stargate fans.

Comment: This question was answered

Comment: @JackBNimble - Brilliant. These answers definitely need to be applied to a blog post as well as some set-piece questions.

Comment: Maybe I'll keep all these answers to myself. Muhahahahahahahahaha

Comment: @JackBNimble - Why you son of a... * shakes fist wildly *

Comment: I realized I never posted a blog post or anything with this answer. First, Season 3 would have been the same, they are out exploring, doing their thing. She described Stargate: Universe as more of a human interest story that takes place on a spaceship rather than a Stargate story. She also said that normal Stargate fans seemed to hate the show. 

As to the fate of the crew, she said based on the discussions and the plans, everyone survived stasis, including Eli.

Comment: @JackBNimble - You should definitely do a blog post.

Answer (score 0):

**Laurie Holden**

- What was Andrea's biggest mistake or regret?
- Who had it more right - the Governor or Rick?

Comment: While not exactly asked, I have quotes that can be applied to these questions.

Comment: I realized I never actually posted the answers. To a question about what Andrea would have done had Rick not killed her (would she stay or go) she said she would have gone and rejoined Rick's group. By that implication, it seems to me she is saying that Rick had it more right than the Governor.