# Salt Lake Comic Con - Ask a Celebrity

Tags: discussion, blog

So I'll be at the Salt Lake Comic Con Press Conference this year. They always have some of the their celebrities attend this conference and make them available for people to go up and ask questions. They never disclose who will be at the press conference before hand, but I'm always impressed by the people there. **If you have questions for people and they are in attendance, I'll try to get an answer.**

I did something similar last spring. [Which questions need a good answer from Word of God at SLCC xFan 2015?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6434/which-questions-need-a-good-answer-from-word-of-god-at-slcc-xfan-2015)

Here are the list of attendees:

- Mark Hamill (**Luke Skywalker: SW, Joker: DCAU**)
- William Shatner (**Jim Kirk: ST**)
- Famke Janssen (**Jean Grey: X-Men**)
- Ian Somerhalder (**Damon Salvatore: Vampire Diaries, Boone Carlyle: Lost**)
- Stephen Amell (**Oliver Queen: Arrow, Casey Jones: TMNT**)
- Michael Rooker (**Merle Dixon: TWD, Yondu Udonta: GotG**)
- Paul Wesley (**Stefan Salvatore: Vampire Diaries**)
- Robert Englund (**Freddie: Nightmare on Elm Street**)
- Danny Trejo (**Machete: Spy Kids**)
- Evanna Lynch (**Luna Lovegood: Harry Potter**)
- Arthur Darvill (**Rory Williams: Doctor Who, Rip Hunter: LoT**)
- Katie Cassidy (**Laurel Lance: Arrow**)
- Billy Boyd (**Peregrin Took: LoTR**)
- Millie Bobby Brown (**Jane 'Eleven' Ives: Stranger Things**)
- Manu Bennet (**Azog: The Hobbit, Slade Wilson: Arrow, Allanon: Shannara Chronicles**)
- Lou Ferrigno (**Incredible Hulk, Avengers**)
- David Ramsey (**John Diggle: Arrow**)
- Sean Maher (**Simon Tam: Firefly, Mark Scheffer: Arrow**)
- Ruth Connell (**Rowena MacLeod: Supernatural**)
- Jim Beaver (**Bobby Singer: Supernatural**)
- Lennie James (**Morgan Jones: TWD**)
- Seth Gilliam (**Father Gabriel Stokes: TWD, Alan Deaton: Teen Wolf, Sugar Watkins: Starship Troopers**)
- Liam McIntyre (**Mark Mardon: The Flash**)
- Emma Caulfield (**Anya: Buffy the Vampire Slayer**)
- Nicholas Brendon (**Xander: Buffy the Vampire Slayer**)
- Tahmoh Penikett (**Capt. Karl Agathon: BSG, Paul Ballard: Dollhouse, Jim Martin: Continuum, Gadreel: Supernatural, Alar of Caer Caladh: Riftworld Chronicles**)
- John Schneider (**Jonathan Kent: Smallville, Bo Duke: Dukes of Hazzard**)

and

- Tom Wopat (**Luke Duke: Dukes of Hazzard**)
- Henry Winkler (**Fonzie: Happy Days**)
- John Cena (**Professional WWE Wrestler**)

That list is subject to change, so a full listing can be seen [here](http://saltlakecomiccon.com/slcc-2016-film-tv/).

Comment: **Mark Hamill**: conclusive answers to [this question](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/106279/31394) and [this question](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/111154/31394) might be nice.

Comment: **Arthur Darvill**: you could ask him [this question](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/126684/31394) if you want to get yourself a Reversal badge :-P

Comment: **Mark Hamill:** I'd really like to know what he thinks about [this](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/112121/have-mark-hamill-and-harrison-ford-commented-on-this-aspect-of-force-awakens).

Comment: I've taken the liberty of editing in their most prominent role/s in scifi and fantasy. The bottom three don't seem to have any credits in scifi or fantasy.

Comment: **Arthur Darvill:** I second Rand al’Thor’s suggestion. Let’s give a Word of God answer to a low-voted question.

Comment: Feel free to post actual answers as question suggestions and not just comments.

Comment: Hmm. It all looks a bit 'actor heavy' for my tastes. I like my answers to come from writers and creatives rather than "on-screen talent" since they're often pretty clueless about what they're reading out :-)

Comment: Well you won't be able to see John Cena, so don't bother.

Comment: This isn't related to the site, but II'd be thankful if you asked Henry Wrinkler if he knows how *Arrested Development* season 5 is coming along.

Answer (score 6):

It would be awesome and much appreciated if you could ask **Mark Hamill** any of the following questions:

- [Was Star Wars changed because of a car crash?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/106279/)
- [Has Mark Hamill commented on this aspect of *The Force Awakens*?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/112121/)
- [Why was Luke Skywalker missing in *The Force Awakens*?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/111154)

Comment: I probably should have mentioned that the top billed guests are never at the press conference, but on the off chance I do get a chance to talk to him, I'll be sure to ask about these questions.

Comment: That second question would be very intriguing!